# Animating draggable object to its starting position

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a div with fixed position so i just can see a tab, when you click on the button on  this div element it displays in the stage and also become draggable, so far so good. Now I am trying to make this same element return to its original position by animaton and i also want it to not be draggable while is hidden as a tab. I´ve been trying with $(some-element).animate(), and i can see on the HTMl that it sets the propierties i give to him but it never gets animated, I also dont know how to remove the draggable function. I am learning all this stuff and i´ll appreciate if someone could help me a bit figuring out how to do this. thank you very much guys!!. ill leave you my jquery code and a fiddle so you guys can see whats going on.

jquery

```
$("#minimize").on("click", display);
function display(){
    if(!$("#box").hasClass("draggable")){
        $("#box").animate({bottom: "20"}).addClass("draggable");
        $(".draggable").draggable();    
        }else{
            $("#box").removeClass("draggable");  
            $("#box").animate({
            bottom: -221
            });    
    }  
}
```

here is te Js fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/xtatanx/PNEhD/

some more info:

The element return to its position if you don´t drag it, but if you drag it around it will not return to its position.

**Second edit:**

so far i come with this, wich is a good improve: http://jsfiddle.net/xtatanx/PNEhD/ 
but i will like to avoid the jump when the style are resetted in roder to make fluid the animation wherever the object is located

Answer (score 3):

It's because the draggable sets the top position and it needs to be cleared before you can animate towards a bottom position because the top is still set.

Here's your updated JS

```
$("#minimize").on("click", display);

function display() {
    if (! $("#box").hasClass("draggable")) {
        $("#box").animate({bottom: "20"}).addClass("draggable");
        $(".draggable").draggable();    
    } else {
        $("#box").removeClass("draggable");  
        $('#box').css('top', '');
        $("#box").animate({
            bottom: -221
        });    
    }  
}
```

Here's a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PNEhD/1/

Comment: hey, this is working good so far for me, but i actually want to to not just go bottom but returns to its starting position so i made this  http://jsfiddle.net/xtatanx/PNEhD/  wich is actually kind of working, i would like to know if tere is a way to avoid the jump it takes when you reset top and left position, in order to make fluid the animation!!

Comment: Looks like you may have worked this out, I'm not seeing any jumpy movements.

Comment: Yeah! I've been working on it and i finally made it, it returns to its position smoothly animated :) ...now I'm working in some more problems like the fact that if you resize the window the draggable object doesn't move relative to the window, so far i just made it to move relative when the box is minimized but not when the box is displayed it is a mess :p