# Animate a draggable element to the bottom

Tags: jquery

I would like to animate an object back to its starting position (bottom/left) in one single smooth move after it has been dragged.
Everything seems to work fine with a top/left starting position though.
As far as I understand, it's because the animate function can't calculate the move as long as the top value hasn't been set.

I made an example:

```
$("#move").click(function(){
    $(".block").animate({"bottom": "9px", "left": "9px"}, "slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tancrede/dztFw/3/

It shouldn't be so much complicated but I'm afraid that my javascript/jquery skills are very limited.

A similar question has been asked and I have the impression that my situation is simpler, but I still don't know how to adapt the script.
[Animating draggable object to its starting position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846978/animating-draggable-object-to-its-starting-position)

It would be great if someone had the time to help me!

Comment: You want to store the initial offsets on the element (top and left) if it's not set, and then when the button is pressed, animate to those.  Look up `$.offset` and `$.data`, and jQuery UI `$.draggable` events.

Answer (score 2):

> I have come up with a solution to this, which may seem a bit hacky but i can't think of any other way at the moment, because the draggable is setting a `top` on the element, and you can't have it at the bottom when you have a top as well, unless your element doesn't have any fixed height. well in your case it does.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ containment: "window" });

$("#move").click(function(){
    var el = $('.block'); // Save the element
    el.animate({
       top: getHeight(el, 9), // Calculate the height with our function
       left: "9px"
    }, "slow");
});

var getHeight = function( elem, extra) {
    return $(window).height() - elem.height() - (extra || 0);
    // here we just calculate the height of the window minus the height of 
    // the element minus the extra 9px that you had by default, and we get a 
    // bottom:9px; effect.
};
```

> In my example we are omitting `bottom` and will use `top` instead, we calculate the `height` of the window, and then take away the `height` of the `element` and any extra you need.

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dztFw/8/)

> **If I can think of a better way, I will add it to the answer.**
>
> **Note -** The reason it won't work your way is because it already has a `top` and you can't animate a `top` to `auto` or `inherit` so it will just jump straight to the `bottom`

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I was looking for! It works great for me! Thank you!